# I have no idea how to solve this question about the principle of inclusion and exclusion. Could anybody help?

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

How many natural numbers are smaller than $2^{30}$ that are not perfect squares, and not perfect cubes, and not fifth perfect powers?

Comment: What happens when you try to use Inclusion-Exclusion in the standard way?

Comment: And maybe first try with some (much) smaller number than $2^{30}$, to get a feel for how it works?